# Is there an adjective equivalent for "more succinct"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, comparatives

Generally speaking, I want to say that x is equivalent to y but one is more succinct than the other, in a single word if possible (because ironically "more succinct" is not very succinct).

E.g: 4 is more succinct than 1+1+1+1.

Comment: 4 is short(er version) of 1+1+1+1?

Comment: @Eilia Yes, it is. And if you're unhappy with the example, you can edit it (I personally don't really care).

Comment: @MasterMastic, No, it's OK. The comment is my suggestion : "shorter". However, I like deadrat's comment (+1).

Comment: @Eilia Oh, excuse me ^^. And yes, I agree (I did think of shorter actually but it doesn't necessarily describe something to be clear, right? Terser works great).

Comment: No problem guy! Probably my comment was not clear, especially "?".

Comment: @MasterMastic Done.

Comment: Succinctlier is succinctlier than more succinct.

Comment: 'Terser' would not usually be used in place of 'more succinct' here. There's at least a fairly strong suggestion of brusqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "terser" fits your requirement.  The word comes from the Latin, *tergere* meaning to wipe or polish, and the *OED* traces its original meaning as applied to language from generally polished and polite to the more particular -- concise, pithy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Edwin that *terse* opens another can of worms.  If it bothers you to say "more succinct", because it's two words, not one, then you might try rewriting your sentence, to use "succinctness".  Example:

> Formulation B is preferred over formulation A for its **succinctness**.